# TFS git conflict resolution issue in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have a TFS 2015 with Git repository. Developers are using VS2013 for all development activities.  We are facing strange issue from last 2 days.

We are doing merge of 2 branches, merge option gives conflicts and we are trying to resolve conflicts in Visual Studio. It gives "Keep Source , Keep Target , Compare and Merge options" and none of the options are working. On click of any options nothing is happening.

Please help us in this. We are stuck in bug updates.

Comment: Did merge work before?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Yes developer were able to merge and they are able to merge other branches except for 2 branches.                                                               As an Admin  able to merge successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with my TFS 2015.3 + VS2013.5, but couldn't reproduce your issue. All options "Keep Source , Keep Target , Compare and Merge options" work as expected.

In order to narrow down the issue, you may check on another client machine to see whether the issue persists, and make sure you have committed and pushed all changes in both branchs. Also, you may try to create a new branch to see whether you can perform merge option.

[image]